# how to count the guess made by the player. Is it possible to count it in this code?

Tags: java, string, int

```
 public class game {
    int[] locks;
    int numberofhits = 0;
    boolean isAlive = true;
    int numberofguess = 0;

    public void setlocation(int[] location) {
        locks = location;
    }

    public String checkyourself(String guess) {
        int guess1 = Integer.parseInt(guess);
        String result = "missed";
        System.out.println("Guess by Player =" + guess);

        for (int cell : locks) {
            if (guess1 == cell) {
                result = "killed";
                isAlive = false;
                numberofhits++;
                break;
            }//if close
        }//for close
        System.out.println("Player you have " + result + " the object");
        while (isAlive == true) {
            System.out.println("Enter another guess buddy");
            break;
        }
        while (isAlive == false) {
            System.out.println("You hit the object");
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Number of object hit by the player is " + numberofhits);
        return result;
    }//method close
}//class close

public class rungame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int randomnumber = (int) (Math.random() * 8);
        int[] location = {randomnumber, randomnumber + 1, 
                randomnumber + 2, randomnumber + 3};
        game player = new game();
        player.setlocation(location);
        player.checkyourself("0");
        System.out.println("Game is Started ...........");
        player.checkyourself("1");
        player.checkyourself("2");
        player.checkyourself("3");
        player.checkyourself("4");
        player.checkyourself("5");
        player.checkyourself("6");
        player.checkyourself("7");
    }//Main Close
}//Class close
```

I want to count the guess made by the user. It is possible to do in this code?
And how can i improve this code? The code is running perfectly right, but i want to count the user guess and is it possible to write `while(isAlive==true)` condition in main method?

Is it possible to limit the user guess with the length of location array?

Comment: You should consider using if/else blocks instead of while and break... Firstly, while is a loop construct (which you don't need as you're doing a simple logic test). Secondly, isAlive can only be true or false, so you don't really need two tests one after the other. A simple if/else would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if i understood you corectly adding

```
numberofguess++;
```

in checkyourselft method will solve your problem.

Comment: yes i implemented that in checkyourself method just below the  int guess1=Integer.parseInt(guess);
         numberofguess++; and now it is giving me a count of 8

Comment: yes, because you have 8 method invocations in rungame class (from 0 to 7)